# postgres db in mapserver getting not found http://localhost/cgi-bin/LAYER157439308110272.png

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, mapserver

**Code LAYER.map file** Layer.map file

```
    MAP
    NAME "LAYER"
    SIZE 400 400
    STATUS ON
    EXTENT 1143759 4417539 1146436 4420390
    UNITS METERS 

    WEB
    TEMPLATE "template.html"
    END

    LAYER
         CONNECTIONTYPE Postgis
            CONNECTION "host=localhost dbname=newmapserver user=postgres password=**** port=5432"
            DATA "geom FROM song"
        NAME "song"
        TYPE POLYGON
        STATUS ON
        CLASS
          STYLE
            COLOR 255 235 190
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            SYMBOL 0
          END
        END
    END

   END
```

**SAMPLE FILE sample.html** sample.html file

```
<html>
<head><title>Creating a simple image using Mapserver and a Shapefile</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<h2>Creating a simple image using Mapserver and a Shapefile</h2>
<p><hr><p>
This page simply contains a link which sends a set of instructions to the Mapserver application using a mapfile.<br />
The information stored within the mapfile tells the Mapserver application how to draw the map.<p>
<!-- The following link sends the local file structure path of the mapfile to the web location of the mapserver executable file  -->
<A HREF="http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\LAYER.map">
Click on this link</A> to view a map generated using a Shapefile.
<p><hr><p>

</body>
</html>
```

**template.html file** template file

```
<!-- MapServer Template -->
<html>
<head><title>Simple Mapserver Template HTML Document</title></head>
<body bgcolor=#AAAAAA>
<h2>The image below was illustrated based on the instructions sent in the mapfile.</h2>
<!-- When using Mapserver with a template, the Mapserver application looks for the [img] tag within the template document to place the map -->
<IMG SRC="[img]" width=400 height=300 border=0>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run the sample.html file and click on link for view I got image not found error 
 getting  not found http://localhost/cgi-bin/LAYER157439308110272.png in console.

Answer (score 0):

Your query template file is not structured properly.  It should look something like this (listing each column required from your database table) :

```
<!-- MapServer Template -->
        <tr>
          <td>[name]</td>
          <td>[description]</td>
        </tr>
```

and you should point to that template file from inside the LAYER such as:

```
        LAYER 
          ...
          CLASS
            ...
            TEMPLATE "template.html"
            ...
          END  # CLASS

        END  # layer
```

I recommend reviewing the full working example in Section 3.1 of the MapServer tutorial at: https://demo.mapserver.org/tutorial/section3.html